# Display specific parent and child from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am currently working with my forum application with admin user.
Is it possible to display different parent and its children in a RecyclerView?

In my current code, i used switch but it only displays the last switch.
Here's my code

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

mDatabaseG1S1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Grade1Section1");
mDatabaseG1S2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Grade1Section2");
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Grade1Section3");
int ctr = 0;

mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
switch(ctr)
    {case 0: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.outer_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase)
        {
         @Override
         protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, final int position) {
         viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
         viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
         viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
         }
         };
        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
    switch(ctr)
    {
        case 0: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.outer_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseG1S1 )
        {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, final int position) {
        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
        viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
            }
        };
        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);        
    }

    switch(ctr)
    {
        case 0: FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
                Blog.class,
                R.layout.outer_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseG1S2 )
        {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, final int position) {
        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
        viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
        }
        };
            mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);   
    }
  }
```

It only display the last switch which is the Grade1Section1 parent and its child

[image]

I wanted to display the children of those parents in a RecyclerView.

Comment: You cannot set multiple adapters on one RecyclerView, so ofcourse it only displays the data retrieved from last switch. Your best bet is to use a custom library, check out this Expandable RecyclerView: http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/

Comment: thanks bro, i'll try it.